# PHP: creating list of text and images shows images overlapping text

Tags: php, html, css

I have an **array-like string containing a variable list of countries, separated by comma**. 
E.g. this could be: Germany,Ireland,Sweden,United States

I am using the following PHP lines in order to add images (country flags) to each of these countries. 
All images are saved under the same name as the countries, except that the image names use underscores instead of spaces.

**Everything works as intended - my only issue is that the images are overlapping the names of the (following) countries.** 
It looks like this happens because loading the images takes longer than getting the text + it adjusts after one or two seconds.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening ?

**My PHP:**

```
$inputCountries = explode(", ", "Germany","Ireland","Sweden","United States"); // hard-coded for testing
foreach($inputCountries as $key => $val) {
$country1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $val); // required to match country and image names
    $inputCountries[$key] = "<img src='images/icons/flags-32/flag_" . $country1 . ".png' alt='' />&nbsp;" . $val . "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
$countries = implode("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $inputCountries);
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: This doesn't look like a PHP issue. It looks like a problem with the HTML/CSS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the problem, but your list of countries should be quoted. It's probably just a typo in the question. In which case I'd tell you to paste your code exactly as you have it so that we see what you're really working with.

Comment: @PatrickQ: Thanks, yes thats just a typo here - will correct.

Comment: Thanks, All. To add here, it is actually not overlapping the country names, just the spaces between images and country names.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, using some css:

```
$inputCountries = explode(", ", "Germany","Ireland","Sweden","United States"); // hard-coded for testing
foreach($inputCountries as $key => $val) {
$country1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $val); // required to match country and image names
    $inputCountries[$key] = "<img src='images/icons/flags-32/flag_" . $country1 . ".png' alt='' style='padding-right: 10px;'/><span style='padding-right: 10px;'>" . $val . "</span>";
}
$countries = implode("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $inputCountries);
```

If needed, you may think about adding `float:left;` to both img and span tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to resolve this.

If I just add a style with the same width as the images (`style='width:32px'`) to the img tags than it keeps the width and spaces even if loading the images takes longer than the rest.

```
$inputCountries = explode(", ", "Germany","Ireland","Sweden","United States"); // hard-coded for testing
foreach($inputCountries as $key => $val) {
$country1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $val); // required to match country and image names
    $inputCountries[$key] = "<img src='images/icons/flags-32/flag_" . $country1 . ".png' alt='' style='width:32px' />&nbsp;" . $val . "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
$countries = implode("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $inputCountries);
```

Answer (score -1):

As Patrick said, the list of countries doesn't look like a string. Also, the delimiter searched for contains a space.

Try:

```
$inputCountries = explode(",", "Germany,Ireland,Sweden,United States"); // hard-coded for testing
```

Phylogenesis is probably also right about the HTML formatting. Try:

```
$inputCountries[$key] = "<span><img src='images/icons/flags-32/flag_" . $country1 . ".png' alt='' /></span>&nbsp;<span>" . $val . "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```